# Passing data across Material-UI Stepper using React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, state, react-hooks, formik

I have a multi-step form that I want to implement in React using `Formik`, `Material-ui`, functional components, and the `getState` hook.

```js
import React, { useState, Fragment } from 'react';
import { Button, Stepper, Step, StepLabel } from '@material-ui/core';
import FormPartA from './FormPartA';
import FormPartB from './FormPartB';
import FormPartC from './FormPartC';

function MultiStepForm(props) {

  const steps = ['Part A', 'Part B', 'Part C'];
  const passedValues = props.values || {};

  const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = useState(0);
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    field1:(( typeof passedValues.field1 === 'undefined' || passedValues.field1 === null ) ? '1' : passedValues.field1 ),
    field2:(( typeof passedValues.field2 === 'undefined' || passedValues.field2 === null ) ? '2' : passedValues.field2 ),
    field3:(( typeof passedValues.field3 === 'undefined' || passedValues.field3 === null ) ? '3' : passedValues.field3 ),
    field4:(( typeof passedValues.field4 === 'undefined' || passedValues.field4 === null ) ? '4' : passedValues.field4 ),
    field5:(( typeof passedValues.field5 === 'undefined' || passedValues.field5 === null ) ? '5' : passedValues.field5 ),
    field6:(( typeof passedValues.field6 === 'undefined' || passedValues.field6 === null ) ? '6' : passedValues.field6 )
  });

  const handleNext = () => {
    alert({...props.values, ...values});
    setValues({...props.values, ...values});
    setActiveStep(activeStep + 1);
  };

  const handleBack = () => {
    setActiveStep(activeStep - 1);
  };

  function thisStep(step) {
    switch (step) {
      case 0:
        return <FormPartA values={values} setValues={setValues}/>;
      case 1:
        return <FormPartB values={values} setValues={setValues}/>;
      case 2:
        return <FormPartC values={values} setValues={setValues}/>;
      default:
        throw new Error('Mis-step!');
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="MultiStepForm">
      <Stepper activeStep={activeStep} className={classes.stepper}>
        {steps.map(label => (
          <Step key={label}>
            <StepLabel>{label}</StepLabel>
          </Step>
        ))}
      </Stepper>
      <Fragment>
        {activeStep === steps.length ? ( 
          <p>You're done!<p>
          ) : (
          <Fragment>
            {thisStep(activeStep)}
            <div className={classes.buttons}>
              {activeStep !== 0 && (
                <Button onClick={handleBack} > Back </Button>
              )}
              <Button onClick={handleNext} >
                {activeStep === steps.length - 1 ? 'Done' : 'Next'}
              </Button>
            </div>
          </Fragment>
        )}
      </Fragment>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Each of the sub-forms, for sake of argument, look roughly like this, with just 2 fields per sub-form:

```js
import React from 'react';

import {Formik, useField, Field, Form} from 'formik';
import { TextField } from 'formik-material-ui';
import * as Yup from "yup";
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core';

export default function BasicForm(props) {

  const field1 = ( typeof props.values.field1 === 'undefined' || props.values.field1 === null ) ? '' : props.values.field1;
  const field2 = ( typeof props.values.field2 === 'undefined' || props.values.field2 === null ) ? '' : props.values.field2;

  return (
    <div>

      <h3>Part A</h3>

      <Formik
        initialValues={{
          field1,
          field2
        }}
        validationSchema={Yup.object({
          field1: Yup.string()
            .required('Required'),
          field2: Yup.string()
            .required('Required'),
        })}
      >
      {({submitForm, isSubmitting, values, setFieldValue}) => (
        <Form>
          <Field name="field1" type="text" label="Field 1" variant="outlined" 
            margin="normal" fullWidth multiline component={TextField} />
          <Field name="field2" type="text" label="Field 2" variant="outlined" 
            margin="normal" fullWidth multiline component={TextField} />
        </Form>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The bit that eludes me is the updating of state. How do I make sure that the child state from each sub-form is saved when stepping between forms? Also, the `(( typeof passedValues.field1 === 'undefined' || passedValues.field1 === null ) ? '1' : passedValues.field1 )` construction seems clumsy?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK, I got it to work, which was lots of fun (for small values of fun). Half the issue was recognising that the `activeStep` value, `handleNext()`, and `handleBack()` functions needed to be passed in to the sub-forms, as well as pre-calculating whether this `isLastStep`:

```js
import React, { useState, Fragment } from 'react';
import { Button, Stepper, Step, StepLabel } from '@material-ui/core';
import FormPartA from './FormPartA';
import FormPartB from './FormPartB';
import FormPartC from './FormPartC';

const steps = ['Part A', 'Part B', 'Part C'];

function MultiStepForm(props) {

  const { field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6, } = props;

  const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = useState(0);
  const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState({
    field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6
  });

  const handleNext = (newValues) => {
    setFormValues({ ...formValues, ...newValues });
    setActiveStep(activeStep + 1);
  };

  const handleBack = (newValues) => {
    setFormValues({ ...formValues, ...newValues });
    setActiveStep(activeStep - 1);
  };

  function getStepContent(step) {
    const isLastStep = (activeStep === steps.length - 1);
    switch (step) {
      case 0:
        return <BasicFormA {...formValues} activeStep={activeStep} isLastStep={isLastStep} handleBack={handleBack} handleNext={handleNext}/>;
      case 1:
        return <BasicFormB {...formValues} activeStep={activeStep} isLastStep={isLastStep} handleBack={handleBack} handleNext={handleNext}/>;
      case 2:
        return <BasicFormC {...formValues} activeStep={activeStep} isLastStep={isLastStep} handleBack={handleBack} handleNext={handleNext}/>;
      default:
        throw new Error('Mis-step!');
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="MultiStepForm">
      <Stepper activeStep={activeStep} className={classes.stepper}>
        {steps.map(label => (
          <Step key={label}>
            <StepLabel>{label}</StepLabel>
          </Step>
        ))}
      </Stepper>
      <Fragment>
        {activeStep === steps.length ? (
           <p>You're done!<p>
        ) : (
        <Fragment> {getStepContent(activeStep)} <Fragment>
        )}
      <Fragment>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MultiStepForm;
```

At this point, the sub-form can check that its fields are valid, before going to the next step:

```js
import React from 'react';

import {Formik, useField, Field, Form} from 'formik';
import { TextField } from 'formik-material-ui';
import * as Yup from "yup";
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core';

export default function BasicForm(props) {

  const { values, field1, field2, activeStep, isLastStep, handleBack, handleNext } = props;

  return (
    <div>
      <Formik
        initialValues={{
          field1,
          field2
        }}
        validationSchema={Yup.object({
          field1: Yup.string()
            .required('Required'),
          field2: Yup.string()
            .required('Required'),
        })}
      >
      {({submitForm, validateForm, setTouched, isSubmitting, values, setFieldValue}) => (
      <Form>
        <Field name="field1" type="text" label="Field 1" variant="outlined" margin="normal" fullWidth multiline component={TextField} />
        <Field name="field2" type="text" label="Field 2" variant="outlined" margin="normal" fullWidth multiline component={TextField} />
      </Form>
      <div>
        {activeStep !== 0 && (
          <Button onClick={() => { handleBack(values) } } className={classes.button}> Back </Button>
        )}
        <Button className={classes.button} variant="contained" color="primary" 
          onClick={
            () => validateForm()
              .then((errors) => {
                if(Object.entries(errors).length === 0 && errors.constructor === Object ) {
                  handleNext(values);
                } else {
                  setTouched(errors);
                }
              })
          } >
          {isLastStep ? 'Submit Draft' : 'Next'}
        </Button>
      </div>
      )}
    </Formik>
  </div>
  );
}
```

The only other trick is remembering to `setTouched(errors)` when the sub-form is invalid, so that untouched fields get their validation errors displayed.

Comment: What are you doing w/props?  I thought they weren't supposed to be changed in child components?  If you're passing in fields from a parent in props, you're changing them in the wizard component (which is the child).  Can you explain why this is not an issue?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're getting at - the changes to data and components are handled in functions passed in to the children, from the parent, `handleNext` and `handlePrev` and the re-render is triggered by changes to `activeStep`.

Comment: OMG. I'm an idiot. Sorry, this was the wrong stack overflow answer I responded to.  My ba!

Answer (score 1):

This is actually my first post ever on StackOverflow, but this helped me so much I had to add to it.

In my case, I wasn't using sub-Forms so instead I went for useState to have an Object to put the answers from the input. I admit it's a bit brute force but it felt a lot easier to manage once I instanced the Object in the hook.

```
const [ edit, setEdit ] = useState({1: '', 2: '', 3: '', 4: '', 5: '', 6: '', 7: '', 8: ''});
const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = useState(0);

const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    setEdit({...edit, [e.target.name]: e.target.value});
}
const handleNext = () => {
setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep + 1);};

const handleBack = () => {
    setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep - 1);
  };
```

I know that a dinamic Object would have been better but with this setup I can use a MUI Input changing only the name and value like this:

```
<Input
  name={`${activeStep + 1}`}
  variant="standard"
  value={edit[`${activeStep + 1}`]}
  onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e)}
  />
```

With this the input value will move with each step, hope it helps others!